# excel vba : selected cells loop

Tags: vba, excel

Would like to iterate each row in a selection in excel VBA.

I have:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim s As String
Set rng = Application.Selection
Debug.Print "c :" & rng.Address
```

This prints

> c :$B$22:$C$29

How to make a loop from row 22 to 29/ parse out the start and end row?

And in separate int variables get the start and end column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterates directly over rows only. I have more than one column selected, wanted outer loop  rows only.

```
Option Explicit

'go over selection, merge text in cells, so all in first column in every row.
Sub mergeCombine()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim s As String
  Set rng = Application.Selection
  Debug.Print "c :" & rng.Address
  s = rng.Column
  Dim cRow As Range



  Debug.Print "c :" & rng.Address & "||" & rng.AddressLocal

  Dim ir, ic As Integer


  For ir = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
      Set cRow = rng.Rows(ir)
      s = ""
      For ic = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
          s = s & cRow.Columns(ic).Text
          Cells(cRow.Row, cRow.Columns(ic).Column).Formula = ""
          If (ic + 1) <= rng.Columns.Count Then
              s = s & " "

          End If
      Next
      Cells(cRow.Row, cRow.Column).Formula = ""
      Cells(cRow.Row, cRow.Column).Formula = s


  Next
End Sub
```

It doesn't work with non-contiguous selection. Count is incorrect with non-contiguous, you'd have to use For Each cRow In rng.Rows I have not tried this myself, my use case was for a contiguous only. Thank you Danny Holstein (comment in 2019)

Comment: Good solution and helpful but with the caveat that it doesn't work with non-contiguous selection. The rng.Columns.Count is incorrect with non-contiguous, you'd have to use `For Each cRow In rng.Rows`

Answer (score 32):

A general solution to looping through a range of cells in Excel:

```
Sub LoopSelection()

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range

    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        Debug.Print cel.Address, cel.Value
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Iterates from top-left most cell, across then down.