# How can you shift selected cell using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a rolling calendar spreadsheet that tracks various metrics and charts them into a spark line.  The script I would like to write would shift the selected range in the spark-lines every time it is ran.

I have done some googlefu and have tried using the offset function to no avail.  This is because the data is in a predefined range defaulting to `num 0` based on the formulas used to populate the spreadsheet int the first place.

[excel vba : selected cells loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526863/excel-vba-selected-cells-loop)

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-entire-column.html

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291308/how-to-select-cells-ranges-by-using-visual-basic-procedures-in-excel

I am stuck at incrementing the `ActiveCell.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Item(1).SourceData` from its current selected range to `PPTracking!G8:R8 ... H8:S8` ... and so on each time the macro is ran.

This is my first time working in VBA and any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Macro4()
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Set selectedRange = PPTracking!F8:Q8
    Range("E5:E6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Item(1).SourceData = "PPTracking!F8:Q8"
    Range("E5:E6").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  Please take a moment to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as "[ask]" and [this checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user.  You're question isn't clear as to where you're "stuck".

Comment: @GrantMeehan please read [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095/1188513)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [`Sparkline.ModifySourceData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Sparkline.ModifySourceData) or directly change the [`Sparkline.SourceData` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sparkline.sourcedata), as it looks like you are currently aiming to do.

This code will shift the `SourceData` 1 column to the right - from `F8:Q8` to `G8:R8`, then to `H8:S8`, etc. - by using the original `SourceData` value as a reference within `Range`, which is then `Offset` by 1 column.

It concatenates the `Parent.Name` to the `Address` to get the full Worksheet Name and cell reference.

```
Sub ShiftSparklineData()
    If ActiveCell.SparklineGroups.Count > 0 Then
        With ActiveCell.SparklineGroups.Item(1)
            .SourceData = "'" & Range(.SourceData).Parent.Name & "'!" & Range(.SourceData).Offset(, 1).Address
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Avoid using `ActiveCell` where possible though; reference the cell(s) with a sparkline using `Sheets("Yoursheetname").Range("Cellreference")`